# Rails Rspec - part of form doesn't appear in integration test (not rendering fields_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing

I have **Pupil** model. So i can save and edit pupil. Pupils has_one **Phone** (and phone belongs_to pupil) and app save pupils with their phones via nested attributes. Everything works excellent in browser but when i try to test updating **Pupil** model i get some troubles.

**Controller**:

```
class PupilsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def edit
    @pupil = Pupil.find( params[:id] )
  end

  def update    
    pupil = Pupil.find( params[:id] )

    if pupil.update_attributes( params[:pupil] )
      redirect_to pupils_path
      ...
    else
      redirect_to edit_pupil_path
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**View** for edit page:

```
<%= form_for @pupil, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= field_set_tag do %>
    ...
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :pupil_address_of_living, "Address of living", :class => "control-label" %>

      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_area :pupil_address_of_living, :rows => 3, 
                        :placeholder => @everpresent_field_placeholder %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr/>

    <%= f.fields_for :pupil_phone do |pp| %>                                              
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= pp.label :pupil_home_number, "Home phone", :class => "control-label" %> 

        <div class="controls">
          <%= pp.text_field :pupil_home_number, :placeholder => @everpresent_field_placeholder %>
        </div>
      </div>
      ...
    <% end %>


    <%= f.submit "Change", :class => "btn btn-large btn-warning" %>
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

My **integration test** which is actually fails:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'spec_helper'

describe "SchoolHeads" do
  before(:each) do
    @attr = {
              :user_login => "iSchool_head",
              :password => "foobar"
            }

    user = User.new( @attr )
    user.user_role = "school_head"
    user.save!
  end

  ...
    describe "Updating" do
      describe "View" do
        before(:each) do
          @ipupil = Factory( :pupil, :pupil_phone => Factory( :pupil_phone ))            
          visit edit_pupil_path( :id => @ipupil.id )
        end 

        it "should have values in forms" do     
          response.should have_selector("form") do |form|
          ... 
          form.should have_selector("input", :name => "pupil[pupil_phone_attributes][pupil_home_number]")
        end
      end
    end
```

**Error** from my **test**:

```
Failure/Error: form.should have_selector( "input",
expected following output to contain a <input name='pupil[pupil_phone_attributes][pupil_home_number]'/> tag:

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pupils/220" class="form-horizontal" id="edit_pupil_220" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    ...      
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="pupil_pupil_address_of_living">Address of living</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <textarea cols="40" id="pupil_pupil_address_of_living" name="pupil[pupil_address_of_living]" rows="3">Moscow</textarea>
       </div>
     </div>

     <hr>

     # Here i should have part of form with phones which is not rendering. 

     <input class="btn btn-large btn-warning" name="commit" type="submit" value="Change">
   </fieldset>
 </form>
```

I have never met such strange problem. Is it bug or something? Is it my mistake?

Comment: Posting this as a comment because I'm not entirely sure. I think it could be because when you create `@ipupil` the relation isn't being set correctly. If you replace `@ipupil = Factory( :pupil, :pupil_phone => Factory( :pupil_phone ))` with: `@ipupil = Factory(:pupil)` and `Factory(:pupil_phone, :user => @ipupil)` does the test pass?

Comment: @pjumble Your suggestion didn't work for me but you gave my idea how to fix that. Also, your idea is absolute right - relation wasn't set correctly. Can you post my code which works now so i could thank you as much as i can?

Code:
`before(:each) do          
            @ipupil = FactoryGirl.create( :pupil )
            @attr_pupil_phones = {
              :pupil_home_number   =>  "8903111111",
              :pupil_mobile_number => "777-33-22"
            }
            @ipupil.create_pupil_phone( @attr_pupil_phones )
            ...
          end `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Thanks very much to **pjumble** who noticed the problem. Problem was that Factory didn't set relation correctly. So i changed code to this:

```
before(:each) do 
  @ipupil = FactoryGirl.create( :pupil ) 
  @attr_pupil_phones = { :pupil_home_number => "8903111111", 
                         :pupil_mobile_number => "777-33-22" } 
  @ipupil.create_pupil_phone( @attr_pupil_phones ) 
  ... 
end
```

Now it works.